# Misunderstanding of the definition of an almost upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

Per Spivak's Calculus (Chap 8 Question 18 of the 4th edition), an almost upper bound of a set $A$ is a number $y$ such that $x\geq y$ for only finitely many $x \in A$. An upper bound for $A$ is any $z$ such that $x\leq z$ for all $x \in A$.

In the proof to the same problem which gives the almost upper bound definition, it is stated that an upper bound is also an almost upper bound. I don't see this though: can't we have an upper bound $z$ such that $z=x$ for infinitely many $x \in A$, so that this $z$ is not an almost upper bound for $A$?

Comment: "can't we have an upper bound z such that z=x for infinitely many x"  No.  If $x = z$ then there is only one such $x$.  $z$ is the only thing that is equal to $z$.  ....  I suppose we should point out we are talking about *sets* that are bound, and we are not talking about converging sequences (although they have similarities).

Comment: .... or to put it another way:  Okay.  let $z = 2\in \mathbb R$.  You are asking what if we have $x = 2$ for an infinite number of real $x$.  Is that possible?  How can you have an infinite number of real numbers all equal to $2$?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is a *set*, so by definition it contains just one instance of any of its elements. There can't be "infinitely many $x \in A$" all equal to $z$. There is at most one.

Comment: That was stupid of me, thanks for setting things straight. May I ask: is there any reason not to use the strict inequality in the definition?

Comment: If you use a strict inequality then an upper bound that happens to be in the set isn't an almost upper bound, which would be grammatically awkward.

Comment: How so? 0 is a finite number, and there would be no $x \in A$ s.t. $x>y$ if $y$ is said upper bound in the set.

Comment: You're right. The definition works just as well with the weak inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: given $z$, how can $z = x$ hold for infinitely many $x$?